# Parametric closures in PHP? (Currying)

Tags: php, parameters, closures

I seem to recall that [Scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheme_(programming_language)) actually had this kind of toy, but I'm not sure. I'm almost sure PHP doesn't and I'm looking for a way to emulate it.

Let's say I have a few closures:

```
$c1 = function($p) use ($obj) { return f($p, $obj, CONSTANT1); };
$c2 = function($p) use ($obj) { return f($p, $obj, CONSTANT2); };
$c3 = function($p) use ($obj) { return f($p, $obj, CONSTANT3); };
...
dostuff($somedata, $c1);
dostuff($somedata, $c2);
dostuff($somedata, $c3);
```

As you can see, the closure code differs only by the constant being used and I'd like to declare only one closure and make it parametric. FYI, `CONSTANT1`, `CONSTANT2` and `CONSTANT3` are not in the `dostuff` scope and I don't want to change the `dostuff` function parameters (because it is part of a public interface), so I can't pass `CONSTANT*` directly to `dostuff` (BTW, `dostuff` would have no reason for accepting parameters for another function, only to hand them off to it: `dostuff` must not be forced to know what the closure needs beyond what `dostuff` itself has to offer).

I'm looking for a way to write the clousure code only once and pass it a value for a placeholder. PHP should then replace the placeholder occurences in the closure code with the specified value at closure USE time, instead of at closure CALL time. It would be something like a dynamic closure code generation. E.g. something like:

```
/* beware, this is not PHP and it does not work */

$c = function($p) use ($obj) placeholder ($ph) { return f($p, $obj, $ph); };
...
dostuff($somedata, $c{CONSTANT1});
dostuff($somedata, $c{CONSTANT2});
dostuff($somedata, $c{CONSTANT3});
```

Please note that I made up the placeholder syntax myself, and it serves only to make my question clear: I hope it succeeds in its mission...

Comment: Given that constants are, well, *constant* (value will be same at time of declaration and execution) and global (no scope issue), this may be a pretty bad example... :)

Comment: You are right, but the point is that `dostuff` has no reason for using those constants, because they have nothing to do with what dostuff does. I don't know how to say that in english... may I just copy this comment in my question?

Comment: Do what you will. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$c = function ($const) use ($obj) {
    return function ($p) use ($const, $obj) {
        return f($p, $obj, $const);
    };
};

doStuff($somedata, $c(CONSTANT1));
```

Comment: Wow. I've not understood this yet, but, if it works, it is absolutelly awesome. Thanks!

Comment: *Higher level functions.* Functions that accept functions as arguments and/or return functions. You might even call this *currying* for poor men. Lots of keywords to look up for you. :)

Comment: Yes! "Currying", that was the keyword they thought me back then when I was at school studying Scheme!

Comment: I'd edit my comments if I could, but it seems that after 5 minutes, any grammar mistake you made will be there for posterity. So yes, when I was at school they TAUGHT me english too, and I THOUGHT it was good to learn irregular verbs... today instead I'm more inclined to believe that, if such mistakes have to show up for the rest of my life, something like TEACHED and THINKED would make a better impression overall... I know, I'm off topic here and I should post this on meta, if ever. And it's likely that this comment contains a lot more grammar mistakes that will be there forever...

Comment: @LucioCrusca I actually rought the opposite conclusion, that more words ought to end in ought. Sounds better to me. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could turn your closure `$c` into a functor, then inject its dependencies as such:

```
class C
{
    private $obj;
    private $constant;
    private $f;

    public function __construct($obj, $constant, $f)
    { 
        $this->obj = $obj;
        $this->constant = $constant;
        $this->f = $f;
    }

    public function __invoke($p)
    {
        return call_user_func_array($this->f, [
            $p, 
            $obj, 
            $constant
        ]);
    }
}

doStuff($somedata, new C($obj, CONSTANT1, $f));
doStuff($somedata, new C($obj, CONSTANT2, $f));
doStuff($somedata, new C($obj, CONSTANT3, $f));
```

Comment: except that anonymous classes exist only from PHP7 and I guess they can't be used for this (because you would be forced to rewrite the anonymous class 3 times), and named classes like yours defeat part of the pourpose of closures (which is having anonymous functions). However thanks a lot for this answer, it's very useful nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

Now here is a possible solution, but I haven't included it in my question because:

- it's an answer
- it's outrageously ugly
- I wonder if there were a cleaner way
- I'm not even sure it actually works

That being said, here is the monster I've come up with:

```
$constant = null;
$c = function($p) use ($obj, &$constant) { return f($p, $obj, $constant); };
...
$constant = CONSTANT1;
dostuff($somedata, $c);
$constant = CONSTANT2;
dostuff($somedata, $c);
$constant = CONSTANT3;
dostuff($somedata, $c);
```